# Only showing the last 2 directories in the terminal prompt?

Tags: terminal

To show the entire directory path we can configure our terminal prompt like this:

```
export PS1="\w: "
```

That will show the entire directory path like this:

```
~/Documents/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/A200-DOCUMENTATION/developer/fs-developer-md:
```

What if we only want to show the current directory and it's container like this:

```
developer/fs-developer-md:
```

Thoughts?  I'm using the bash shell ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to throw this out there for the few `ksh` users on the Mac besides myself.  I did not create this, I just use it.

```
# Discipline function for relative present working directory
# by Martijn Dekker <martijn@inlv.org> 2020-08-09; public domain
function _relative_pwd.get
{
    typeset del ellip=$'\u2026' v=$PWD keep=*/*   # add /* for each element to keep
    ((${#ellip}==1)) || ellip='...'
    [[ ($v == "$HOME" || $v == "$HOME"/*) && $HOME != / ]] && v=\~${v#"$HOME"}                                          
    del=${v%/$keep}/
    [[ $v == /*/$keep ]] && v=$ellip/${v#"$del"}
    [[ $v == \~/*/$keep ]] && v=\~/$ellip/${v#"$del"}
    .sh.value=$v
}
```

And set `PS1`

> $ PS1="\${_relative_pwd} $ "

Example resulting prompt...

`~/…/ksh/arch $`

Comment: Any chance you have something that works in a bash shell?

Comment: Oh wait .. this works ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216953/show-only-current-and-parent-directory-in-bash-prompt/217097#217097. ... thanks to @mmmmmm

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216953/show-only-current-and-parent-directory-in-bash-prompt/217097#217097 is REALLY ugly, and I'm not sure I understand from the discussion why overloading `cd` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

[Per the Unix StackExchange Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216953/show-only-current-and-parent-directory-in-bash-prompt/217097#217097), this will do the trick (I'm using a bash shell):

```
vi ~/.bash_profile`
```

And add

```
export PS1='${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"} \$ '
```

Then save and `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: For an actual answer see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217097/5140

Comment: Yeah ... It only works initially ....

Comment: @Ole That works fine in `ksh` and `bash`.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you.  I think my main objection to it would be that it doesn't give any indication of how deep you are.  Don't ever export PS1, though.